# Device Tree Overlay fragment notifies and loads children twice

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, device-tree

I have the following device tree overlay fragment, and when it's loaded, `spidev` is added twice:

```
fragment@0 {
    target = <&fpga>;
    __overlay__ {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;

        spi2@600 {
            status = "okay";
            compatible = "opencores,spiocv2";
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            reg = <0 0x800>;
            cell-index = <2>; // bus number

            spidev0 {
                 spi-max-frequency = <25000000>;
                 reg = <0>;
                 compatible = "spidev";
            };
        };
    };
};
```

1. first via `of_overlay_create -> ... -> notifier_call_chain -> of_platform_notify -> ... -> device_attach -> ... -> spioc_driver_probe -> spi_register_master -> of_register_spi_devices -> of_register_spi_device -> spi_add_device`
2. then again via `of_overlay_create -> ... -> notifier_call_chain -> of_spi_notify -> of_register_spi_device -> spi_add_device`

Because it is first loaded correctly, `/dev/spidev2.0` is available and works fine, but the second call leads to ugly errors:

```
[    1.814623] opencores_spi 13e0000f3300000.spi2: chipselect 0 already in use
[    1.836491] spi_master spi2: spi_device register error /fpga/spi2@600/spidev0
[    1.857652] of_spi_notify: failed to create for '/fpga/spi2@600/spidev0'
[    1.877495] __of_changeset_entry_notify: notifier error @/fpga/spi2@600/spidev0
```

What is a clean and proper way to prevent it from being loaded twice? Or how can I prevent the notifier from notifying the platform *and* SPI?